# Surface integral - spherical

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I'm trying to calculate the following surface integral $$\int \int_{s_r} \frac{z-R}{(x^2+y^2+(z-R)^2)^{3/2}} dS $$, where $s_r=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2 \}. $

I've switched to spherical coordinates but don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Do you know Gauss' theorem?

Comment: No. Is there another way to it?

Comment: Can you post your attempt in spherical polar coordinates? It may be useful for us...

Comment: I don't really understand how to do adorable integral using spherical coordinates - surely in spherical coordinates we have 3 variables but how can this be if it's a double integral essentially.

Comment: *double - not adorable.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to use spherical coordinates is that the surface over which we integrate takes on a particularly simple form: instead of the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$ in Cartesians, or $z^2+\rho^2=r^2$ in cylindricals, the sphere is simply the surface $r'=r$, where $r'$ is the variable spherical coordinate. This means that we can integrate directly using the two angular coordinates, rather than having to write one coordinate implicitly in terms of the others.

---

So in spherical coordinates, $dS = r^2 \sin{\theta} \, d\theta \, d\phi$. The integral becomes
$$ \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \frac{r\cos{\theta}-R}{(r^2 -2 rR\cos{\theta + R^2})^{3/2}} r^2\sin{\theta} \, d\phi \, d\theta = r^2 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \frac{r\cos{\theta}-R}{(r^2 -2 rR\cos{\theta + R^2})^{3/2}} \sin{\theta} \, d\theta. $$
Putting $u=\cos{\theta}$ gives
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{u-(R/r)}{(1-2u(R/r)+(R/r)^2)^{3/2}} \, du $$
It makes sense to write $R/r=a$ at this point, so
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \frac{u-a}{(1-2ua+a^2)^{3/2}} \, du. $$
The easiest way to do this integral is by a sort of partial fractions idea: the integrand is
$$ \frac{u-a}{(1-2ua+a^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{2a}\left(\frac{a^2-1}{(1-2ua+a^2)^{3/2}} - \frac{1}{(1-2ua+a^2)^{1/2}} \right), $$
which has either
$$ \frac{1-ua}{a^2(1-2ua+a^2)^{1/2}} \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{1-u/a}{a^2(1/a^2-2u/a+1)^{1/2}} $$
as continuous antiderivative, depending on whether $R$ is smaller or larger than $r$.

Comment: Note: a factor of $2\pi$ is missing, from the integral wrt $\phi$. Should be $2\pi r^2$ in the RHS of the first equation

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left.\iint_{\Large s_{r}}{z - R \over
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} + \pars{z - R}^{2}}^{3/2}}\,\dd S\,
\right\vert_{\substack{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}\ =\ r^{2}
                       \\[1mm]
                       z\ =\ r\cos\pars{\theta}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald{}{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 \over
\root{r^{2} -2rR\cos\pars{\theta} + R^{2}}}\,r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\xi\ =\ \cos\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,
\left.2\pi r^{2}\,\partiald{}{R}\int_{-1}^{1}
{\dd\xi \over \root{r^{2} -2rR\xi + R^{2}}} =
2\pi r^{2}\,\partiald{}{R}{\root{r^{2} -2rR\xi + R^{2}} \over -rR}
\,\right\vert_{\ \xi\ =\ -1}^{\ \xi\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\pi r\,\partiald{}{R}
{\root{r^{2} - 2rR + R^{2}} - \root{r^{2} + 2rR + R^{2}} \over R} =
-2\pi r\,\partiald{}{R}
{\verts{r -R} - \pars{r + R} \over R}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[#ffe,25px,border:1px dotted navy]{\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{\phantom{-\,}0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{R < r}
\\[2mm]
\ds{-\,{4\pi r^{2} \over R^{2}}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{R > r}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use parametric representation to solve the surface integral 
\begin{array}{l}
x = r\sin \phi \cos \theta \\
y = r\sin \phi \sin \theta \\
z = r\cos \phi 
\end{array}
Where, 
$$0 \le \phi  \le \pi ,\,\,\,0 \le \theta  \le 2\pi $$
That is,
$${\rm{r}}\left( {\phi ,\theta } \right) = r\sin \phi \cos \theta \widehat i + r\sin \phi \sin \theta \widehat j + r\cos \phi \widehat k$$
Compute the cross product of the Tangent Vectors

$${T_\phi } \times {T_\theta } = \left| {\matrix{
   {\widehat i} & {\widehat j} & {\widehat k}  \cr 
   {{{\partial x} \over {\partial \phi }}} & {{{\partial y} \over {\partial \phi }}} & {{{\partial z} \over {\partial \phi }}}  \cr 
   {{{\partial x} \over {\partial \theta }}} & {{{\partial y} \over {\partial \theta }}} & {{{\partial z} \over {\partial \theta }}}  \cr 
 } } \right|$$
This will give,
$$\left| {{T_\phi } \times {T_\theta }} \right| = {r^2}\sin \phi $$

---

Now Calculate the integral, 
$$\displaylines{
  \int\!\!\!\int_{{s_r}} {{{z - R} \over {{{({x^2} + {y^2} + {{(z - R)}^2})}^{3/2}}}}dS}  \cr 
   = \int\!\!\!\int_D {\left( {{{r\cos \phi  - R} \over {{{({{\left( {r\sin \phi \cos \theta } \right)}^2} + {{\left( {r\sin \phi \sin \theta } \right)}^2} + {{(r\cos \phi  - R)}^2})}^{3/2}}}}} \right)\left| {{T_\phi } \times {T_\theta }} \right|dA}  \cr 
   = \int\!\!\!\int_D {\left( {{{r\cos \phi  - R} \over {{{\left( {{r^2} + {R^2} - 2rR\cos \phi } \right)}^{3/2}}}}} \right)\left( {r^2\sin \phi } \right)dA}  \cr 
   = \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^\pi  {\left( {{{r\cos \phi  - R} \over {{{\left( {{r^2} + {R^2} - 2rR\cos \phi } \right)}^{3/2}}}}} \right)\left( {r^2\sin \phi } \right)d\phi d\theta } }  \cr} $$

solve this integral.